# n900 windows xp driver

Tags: drivers, tethering, nokia-n-series

I am still looking for a n900 driver so that I can plug my Nokia n900 into my Windows XP laptop and tether it or use it as mass storage.

I still can't quite seem to find a driver for it.  Has anyone found a driver for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed Nokia PC Suite, most likely it will install the needed driver

http://nds1.nokia.com/files/support/global/phones/software/Nokia_Ovi_Suite_webinstaller_ALL.exe

.